# Original location of styles in compiled browser output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

In Rails 3, the application.css file that the browser receives (dev environment) included comments above every CSS style with the filename and line number of the original SCSS style. This output seems to be gone in Rails 4; is it possible to bring this back, either via the config or a gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Rails 4.1 is now doing this with `@imported` SASS files, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I ran `sass --help` and found these lines in the output:

```
-g, --debug-info      Emit extra information in the generated CSS that can be used by the FireSass Firebug plugin.
-l, --line-numbers    Emit comments in the generated CSS indicating the corresponding source line.
    --line-comments
```

Hopefully any of these options will help you.

Happy to help

Comment: Looks promising! But how would I activate this in a Rails application?

Comment: I'm unfortunatelly not very versatile with Rails. There should exist guides pointing you in the right direction though.